# How to use "Threading" / Parallel methods in XAML UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I previously used Threading functions in `WinForms` but not I have a project that uses `XAML`.

I am working out with a simple robot that has `Odometry`. Right now, I am trying to implement 2 process simultaneously specifically..
Starting the Motors(forward, backward, left, right) and
Counting the encoders (number of rotations it turns or number of encoder ticks)

My problem is that after my I press the `forward button` (or any motor button), my UI stops and doesn't perform the `StartCount()` function and doesn't change my `TextBoxes` according to the number of ticks.

Is there any way I could thread these 2 methods? And threading in XAML UWP does not work.

Here is my code:

```cs
private void Forward_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    StartStop_Bool = true;
    
    CwCcwPinLeft.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    CwCcwPinRight.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    
    Task.Delay(FIFTEEN_MILLISECOND);
    
    RunBrakePinRight.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    RunBrakePinLeft.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    
    StartCount();
}
```

`Startcount()` function :

```cs
private void StartCount() 
{

    if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High &&
        TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) 
    {
        if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High &&
            CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low) 
        { 
            // MOVING ON A STRAIGHT LINE
            LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
            RightMotor_TickCounter++;
        } 
        else if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High &&
            CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) 
        { 
            // ROTATING TO RIGHT
            LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
            RightMotor_TickCounter--;
        } 
        else if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low &&
            CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) 
        { 
            // MOVING BACKWARDS
            LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
            RightMotor_TickCounter--;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // ROTATING TO LEFT
            LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
            RightMotor_TickCounter++;
        }
   } 
    else if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High &&
        TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low) 
    {
    
        if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) 
        {
            LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
        }
    } 
    else if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low &&
        TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High) 
    {
        if (CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low) 
        {
            RightMotor_TickCounter++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            RightMotor_TickCounter--;
        }
   }
   
    CounterLabelLeft.Text = LeftMotor_TickCounter.ToString();
    CounterLabelRight.Text = RightMotor_TickCounter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What else would you expect? You run whole code synchronously, on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would use async await to keep ui responsive.  It will allow stuff to happen in background and the UI to stay responsive.   I would change StartCount to something like this.  Any function you run async you should return something.   I am assuming your app is using a .net version that supports async and await

```
private async Task<bool> StartCount() {

    if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
        {
            if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
            { // MOVING ON A STRAIGHT LINE
                LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
                RightMotor_TickCounter++;
            }
            else if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
            { // ROTATING TO RIGHT
                LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
                RightMotor_TickCounter--;
            }
            else if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low && CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
            { // MOVING BACKWARDS
                LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
                RightMotor_TickCounter--;
            }
            else
            { // ROTATING TO LEFT
                LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
                RightMotor_TickCounter++;
            }
        }
        else if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            if (CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
            {
                LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                LeftMotor_TickCounter--;
            }
        }
        else if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low && TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
        {
             if (CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
            {
                RightMotor_TickCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                RightMotor_TickCounter--;
            }
        }
        CounterLabelLeft.Text = LeftMotor_TickCounter.ToString();
        CounterLabelRight.Text = RightMotor_TickCounter.ToString();

        return true;
}
```

And your event handler to this. The awaits will allow the UI to update while the function is running.

```
private async void Forward_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartStop_Bool = true;
    CwCcwPinLeft.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    CwCcwPinRight.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    await Task.Delay(FIFTEEN_MILLISECOND);
    RunBrakePinRight.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    RunBrakePinLeft.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
    await StartCount();
}
```

Another option would be to do this in a thread and use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke when ever you update a control from the thread.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx